# Modifying records sourced in a joined query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I cannot update records on a form which it's record source in a simple SQL select query (containing 2 joined tables linked to a combo box value).  I have ensured that all the properties of each field and the form itself are set for editing but unfortunately when I go into the fields, although it lets me enter, I cannot make any changes. Is it possible that this is the case because the records are sourced from a query ?

Below is the routine which queries the data and maps the record source to the form triggered by the 'after update' event on the combo box used to filter the records. The data table that I am trying to update is '`tblValueChain02`' and is extracted from the `string SQL_GET2` and fed into the form `frmStaticDataDepartments06`.

```
Private Sub cboTeams_AfterUpdate()

    Dim SQL_GET As String
    Dim SQL_GET2 As String

    SQL_GET = "SELECT * from tblValueChain01 where tblValueChain01.MacroProcess = '" & cboTeams & "'"
    SQL_GET2 = "SELECT tblValueChain01.MacroProcess, tblValueChain02.AutoNumbering, tblValueChain02.MicroProcesso02, tblValueChain02.Notes, tblValueChain02.Remarks FROM tblValueChain02 INNER JOIN tblValueChain01 ON tblValueChain02.IDMacroProcesso01 = tblValueChain01.IDMacroProcesso WHERE (tblValueChain01.MacroProcess = '" & [cboTeams] & "')"


    frmStaticDataDepartments04.Visible = True
    frmStaticDataDepartments04.Requery
    frmStaticDataDepartments05.Visible = True
    frmStaticDataDepartments06.Visible = True

    lblProduct.Visible = True
    lblDepartment.Visible = True
    lblTeam.Visible = True

    Me.frmStaticDataDepartments05.Form.RecordSource = SQL_GET
    Me.frmStaticDataDepartments06.Form.RecordSource = SQL_GET2
    Me.frmStaticDataDepartments06.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to contain more info? The code of the query behind the form? Do you get any errors (like `Recordset not updatable`)? I am not certain of what are you trying do.

Comment: Hello Marek. I updated the question with my code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Marek, I have updated the query as you instructed to be a join query, but the result does not change.

Comment: I think pictures at this point would be helpful as I still have little idea what are you trying to do. Please post sample data of your tables, picture of your UI and of what would your result look like, and especially any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your second query, where your are using what is called a [Cross join](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php), and these are not updateable. You will need to redesign the query using standard `INNER JOIN`, if possible.

If you post more info, like screenshots of your app and sample data of those two tables, it would help to see what to do next.

Comment: That is an enourmouse help. I will try to put an inner join and see what happens